# Java, read signed and unsigned from file

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to read a list of positive and negative integers from a file and store them in an array using scanner. The problem is it's not reading the negative values. Here's the input:

```
7 4 5 8 2 4 7 5 0 8 2 3 9 23 48 -12 49
```

Here's the code I have now:

```
try {
        Scanner input=  new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        key = input.nextInt();
        while(input.hasNextInt())
        {
            nums[count] = input.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        input.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No file \""+args[0]+"\" found!");
    }
```

The problem is it quits on the first negative value.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an additional `-` hidden with an escape character in your file. If you paste the line that you've given into an editor that renders them, you get:

> 7 4 5 8 2 4 7 5 0 8 2 3 9 23 48 --12 49

where `--12` is obviously not a proper integer to be read.

Comment: Wow! Good finding!

Comment: sorry , that's not there in the real input file.

Comment: @user6950289 it is, it's just not visible. Try to remove everything in between the 48 and 12 and replace it with a simple `-`.

Comment: The extra character (before the OP edited the question) was a [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen).